# ios angular App: get remote images

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Good day everyone!

I developing an ios app with ionic+cordova framework. The conception is: app takes a photo and merge it with canvas with other remote image. But I can't get remote images. I mean they come from remote storage (I'm using Amazon S3) when app is testing in Chrome, but on emulate app they aren't displaying. If they keep at app folder - it's OK.

Can you tell me what is the best way to load remote images with high resolution at ios app? Maybe anybody could help me?

P.S. My strategy is:
At server side image load to Amazon with link response. That link goes to MongoDB. Mobile App must take that link and render image.

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll have to whitelist your amazon s3;
in the latest Apache Cordova 4.0.0 Android and iOS release you’re required to whitelist any external resources that you want to use.  By default everything is blacklisted.

1. Install the latest [Apache Cordova Whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) Plugin like the following:

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist

2. To allow everything, add the following to your www/index.html file right below the other meta tags:

> `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. Still not available on device, but available at Chrome. Tried both variations.

Comment: try to follow the doc here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html